# How can I tell Vue where my backend is when accesing through network IP instead of localhost?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following setup: Vue is running on localhost:8080 as an SPA, and Laravel backend is running on localhost:80 as an API Rest. Now everything on my pc works perfectly fine.

But when I try to view my localhost web app on my phone through the network IP, Vue is not connecting to the backend correctly. I access to the frontend on my phone with my network IP 192.168.1.38:8080

I do see my vue SPA but it is not retrieving data from the backend. I have set up the backend URL through a env file on my vue project: VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:80/api

I set up a laravel route so that I can check the status of the API, if i go to 192.168.1.38:80/api/status in my phone I can see it works perfectly fine. Could the problem vue on my phone is calling the backend on http://localhost:80 instead of 192.168.1.38:80 ?

If that is the case, how can I tell my vue project to dynamically change the backend URL, to localhost:80/api when on my pc and to 192.168.1.38:80 on my phone?

I'm a bit lost here, thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear if you use Vue CLI. It has builtin proxy feature that can make /api available on the same host as Vue app, so you won't have this problem

Comment: I am indeed using vue CLI but I dont know how to configure the proxy feature.

Comment: Check https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. You need to set your api url as the IP address in your vue app i.e. `192.168.1.38:80/api/...`
you could potentially use some javascript to check if your on a mobile device and change the url dynamically but the IP i believe should work both on local and from the mobile device